# Is it possible to change property shape with mapped types?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have type like this

```
type Foo = {
   x : Bar<A>
   y : Bar<B>
}
```

or

```
type Foo = {
  x: {item:A}
  y: {item:B}
}
```

And I want to express this type

```
{
  x: A
  y: B
}
```

In pseudocode it could look like this

```
type Flatten<T> = {
    [P in keyof T where T[P] extends {item: X}]: X;
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the second variant of `Foo`, where a type of each member   has itself a member with the same name (`item`), so you can use indexed access type operator `['item']` inside mapped type:

```
type A = string;
type B = number;

type Foo = {
  x: {item:A}
  y: {item:B}
}

type M<F extends {[n in string]: { item: {} }}> = {
    [n in keyof F]: F[n]['item']
}

type U = M<Foo>; // type U = { x: string; y: number; }
```

Comment: Could you explain `[n in string]` syntax? Is it the same as `[n: string]`?

Comment: For `string`, they are similar. `[n in string]` is a key in [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-string-index-signatures), `[n: string]` is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).Index signatures were added to the language earlier than  mapped types and index type can be only `string` or `number`,so you can't have`[n: keyof Foo]`.On the other hand,an interface can declare index signature- `interface I { [n: string]:string };` is OK, `interface I { [n in string]:string };`is not